# Hierarchical models and fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, cross-section

I'm trying to model some data using hierarchical models. I have the data at two levels, I have information for different firms in seven countries, $Y_{ij}$. So, the data is a firm-country level.

I have some independent variables at the two levels to include in the model. At firm-level I have employment and assets, and at second-level I have taxes rate for each country. The hierarchical model assuming random intercept and random slope (without interaction) would be:

$Y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} +\beta_{1j} Employment_{ij} + \beta_{2j} Assets_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$

$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01} Taxes_j + u_{oj}$

$\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} + u_{1j}$

$\beta_{2j} = \gamma_{20} + u_{2j}$

where
$i = 1,...,N$ are the N firms and $j=1,...,7$ the countries.

So, the mixed model (or the extended model) is:

$Y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01} Taxes_j + \gamma_{10} Employment_{ij} + \gamma_{20} Assets_{ij} + u_{1j} Employment_{ij} + u_{2j} Assets_{ij} + u_{0j} + \epsilon_{ij}$

According to this, I have the following questions:

1. As it is usual, should I include country dummies to control for country fixed effects?

If the above answer is **yes**,

2. Those independent variables would be at the second-level?